# Cordova iOS iPad app Html5 video displays above canvas on screen with video controls

Tags: ios, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am building a cordova app that draws video on a html5 canvas and additional canvas layers on top of the video canvas to become a touch screen interface and do specific actions depending on where you touched on the top canvas layer. It works well as a Web Application and as a cordova Android App but has issues with cordova iOS iPad OS 10.3

The issue is that as a cordova ios app on my iPad the html5 video element gets drawn on top of all other canvas layers and displays video controls. If I minimize the video, I can then see all the other canvas layers drawn correctly underneath. I think this is an iOS OS issue.

I have tried many different css solutions found on various forums, but have not gotten any successful results.
Many of the css I tried :

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
display: none!important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
display: none!important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
display: none!important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure{
display: none!important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
display:none !important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.video-background::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
.video-background::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
display: none !important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

I even tested the example code on developer.apple.com
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html

And that does not work either when building and testing the cordova ios app on my iPad.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know this environment so there might be a better solution, but a workaround could be to draw your video on the canvas and not display the video element at all.

Comment: I am doing that, but I am pretty sure you have to have a html video element in the background to take snapshots of and draw onto the canvas. So the video is in the background playing, but you are drawing the frames onto the canvas. Not sure if there is another way of doing it?

Comment: You don't have to append it to the DOM in order to draw it on the canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido If I document.createElement('video') and not append it, it still behaves the same way.

Comment: So you mean that an element which is not appended to the doc is displayed? Definitely a bug... Maybe related to their new rules about autoplaying, though as I said, I don't know cordova on ios environment, only web for me... (and you said it works as a web-app, right?)

Comment: @Kaiido Yes. I tried both on the Dom and just a created object. It works well as a web app either way. It is definitely something specific to iOS and html5 videos, I just don't know the magical code solution that I can apply to my web code and or cordova compilation to make the iOS app not go full screen and display the media player controls.